# hi why my list item turn null in the futurebuilder of flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, list, listview, flutter-futurebuilder

Hi in my flutter app have FutureBuilder that return listview, my list listview create some button for update the hive table. when I click the first time on one of buttons everything is run smoothly, but when I click on same button again my hive key turn to null and program show my this error: "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int' "
I write print all over my code but still I do not get it why the key turn null from the second time.
How can I Correct this? please help my.
my Futurebuilder body is:

```
                              FutureBuilder<List>(
                            future: controller.showTaskList(),
                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                                  return SizedBox(
                                    height: Get.height,
                                    child: const Center(
                                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                default:
                                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                    return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                                  } else {
                                    List data = snapshot.data ?? [];

                                    return ListView.separated(
                                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                      physics:
                                      const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                      shrinkWrap: true,
                                      itemCount: data.length,
                                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                        // controller.taskIconCheckList
                                        //     .clear();

                                        for (int i = 0;
                                        i < data.length;
                                        i++) {
                                          if (data[i].status == true) {
                                            controller.taskIconCheckList
                                                .add(true.obs);
                                          } else {
                                            controller.taskIconCheckList
                                                .add(false.obs);
                                          }
                                        }
                                        return ListTile(
                                          leading: Obx(
                                                () => PageTransitionSwitcher(
                                              transitionBuilder: (
                                                  child,
                                                  primaryAnimation,
                                                  secondaryAnimation,
                                                  ) {
                                                return SharedAxisTransition(
                                                  animation:
                                                  primaryAnimation,
                                                  secondaryAnimation:
                                                  secondaryAnimation,
                                                  transitionType:
                                                  SharedAxisTransitionType
                                                      .horizontal,
                                                  fillColor:
                                                  Colors.transparent,
                                                  child: child,
                                                );
                                              },
                                              duration: const Duration(
                                                  milliseconds: 800),
                                              child: controller
                                                  .taskIconCheckList[
                                              index]
                                                  .value
                                                  ? SizedBox(
                                                child: IconButton(
                                                  icon: const Icon(
                                                    Icons
                                                        .check_circle_rounded,
                                                    color: Colors
                                                        .lightGreenAccent,
                                                  ),
                                                  onPressed: () {
                                                    controller
                                                        .functionTaskIconCheckList(
                                                      index,
                                                    );
                                                    print('طول دیتا');
                                                    print(data.length.toString());
                                                    print('مقدار ایندکس');
                                                    print(index.toString());
                                                    print('مقدار کلید');
                                                    print(data[index].key.toString());
                                                    print(data[index].taskText.toString());

                                                    controller
                                                        .updateStatusTask(
                                                        index,
                                                        data[index]
                                                            .key); // here when i first click // return key currectly, but after that show null and updatestatusetask not run and show error.
                                                  },
                                                ),
                                              )
                                                  : IconButton(
                                                onPressed: () {
                                                  controller
                                                      .functionTaskIconCheckList(
                                                    index,
                                                  );
                                                  print('طول دیتا');
                                                  print(data.length.toString());
                                                  print('مقدار ایندکس');
                                                  print(index.toString());
                                                  print('مقدار کلید');
                                                  print(data[index].key.toString());
                                                  print(data[index].taskText.toString());
                                                  controller
                                                      .updateStatusTask(
                                                      index,
                                                      data[index]
                                                          .key);  // here when i first click // return key currectly, but after that show null and updatestatusetask not run and show error. 
                                                },
                                                icon: const Icon(
                                                  Icons
                                                      .radio_button_unchecked_outlined,
                                                  color: Colors.red,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          title: Text(data[index].taskText,
                                              style: normalTextForCategory),
                                          subtitle: Text(
                                            data[index]
                                                .date
                                                .toString()
                                                .substring(0, 10),
                                            textDirection:
                                            TextDirection.ltr,
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                            style: normalTextForSubtitle,
                                          ),
                                          trailing: Row(
                                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                            children: [
                                              IconButton(
                                                onPressed: () {
                                                  myDefaultDialog(
                                                    'هشدار',
                                                    'آیا از حذف این گزینه اطمینان دارید؟',
                                                    'بله',
                                                    'خیر',
                                                        () {
                                                      Get.back();
                                                      mySnakeBar(
                                                          '',
                                                          'گزینه مورد نظر با موفقیت حذف شد.',
                                                          Icons
                                                              .warning_amber_rounded,
                                                          Colors.yellow);
                                                    },
                                                  );
                                                },
                                                icon: const Icon(
                                                    Icons.delete),
                                                color: Colors.redAccent,
                                              ),
                                              IconButton(
                                                onPressed: () {
                                                  Get.offNamed(
                                                      Routs.editTaskScreen,
                                                      arguments: 'edit');
                                                },
                                                icon: const Icon(
                                                  Icons.edit_calendar,
                                                  color:
                                                  Colors.yellowAccent,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      },
                                      separatorBuilder:
                                          (BuildContext context,
                                          int index) {
                                        return const Divider(
                                          height: 2,
                                          color: Colors.white70,
                                        );
                                      },
                                    );
                                  }
                              }
                            },
                          ),
```

this is my functionTaskIconCheckList form controller:

```
 functionTaskIconCheckList(int index) {
taskIconCheckList[index].value = !taskIconCheckList[index].value;}
```

and this the updatestatusetask function

```
  updateStatusTask(int index,int taskKey) async {
print('در تابع آپدیت ایندکس هست: ${index.toString()}');
print('در تابع آپدیت کی هست: ${taskKey.toString()}');
var taskBox = await Hive.openBox('task');
var filterTask = taskBox.values.where((task) => task.key == taskKey).toList();
Task task = Task(
    filterTask[0].taskText,
    filterTask[0].date,
    taskIconCheckList[index].value,
    filterTask[0].deleteStatus,
    null,
    null,
    filterTask[0].taskCatId,
    filterTask[0].userId);
await taskBox.put(taskKey, task);}
```

and this is my showtasklist function:

```
  Future<List> showTaskList() async {
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var taskBox = await Hive.openBox('task');

var filterTask = taskBox.values
    .where((task) => task.userId == sharedPreferences.getInt('key'))
    .toList();
return filterTask;}
```

this is my model:

```
 @HiveType(typeId: 2)
class Task  extends HiveObject{

  @HiveField(0)
  String taskText;
  @HiveField(1)
  DateTime date;
  @HiveField(2)
  bool status;
  @HiveField(3)
  bool deleteStatus;

  @HiveField(4)
  int taskCatId;

  @HiveField(5)
  int userId;

  @HiveField(6)
  User? user;

  @HiveField(7)
  TaskCat? taskCat;

  Task(this.taskText, this.date, this.status, this.deleteStatus, this.user,
      this.taskCat, this.taskCatId, this.userId);
}
```

Comment: Can you include more about `showTaskList`

Comment: yes wait minute please

Comment: can you add the part you save your data in SharedPreferences ?

Comment: this is my saved data on it. await sharedPreferences.setInt('key', filterUser[0].key);

Comment: can you include Task model class? @sadegh

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to wait for the Future function to finish and then load the list. If it tries to load the list early before finishing up the Future function, it might presume the value to be null.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so if the problem come from this. how can i fix it?

Comment: also none of the other list value of that index turn to null. only the key value change :|

Answer (score 0):

Still I do not know what is cause this problem, But I found an alternative temporary solution. I create temporary Int list. then just before the return listTile in the futureBuilder body, I write the Loop and save all of the key in that list. finally instead of pass the "data[index].key." I pass my key from that temporary Int list. so everything work fine now

this is my part of code change from before, but still I want know main solution.

```
 return ListView.separated(
                                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                            physics:
                                                const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                            shrinkWrap: true,
                                            itemCount: data.length,
                                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                              // controller.taskIconCheckList
                                              //     .clear();

                                              for (int i = 0;
                                                  i < data.length;
                                                  i++) {
                                                Get.find<
                                                    HomeScreenController>()
                                              .taskKey.add(data[i].key);
                                                if (data[i].status == true) {
                                                  Get.find<
                                                          HomeScreenController>()
                                                      .taskIconCheckList
                                                      .add(true.obs);
                                                } else {
                                                  Get.find<
                                                          HomeScreenController>()
                                                      .taskIconCheckList
                                                      .add(false.obs);
                                                }
                                              }
                                              return ListTile(
```